# CardView setCardBackground Color not working in code

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to solve this for, more than 3 hours.

JellyBeab 4.1.6

I have a layout which contains card view and i'm setting the setCardbackground color programatically.

What i've tried so far is

```
    CARD = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardMechInfo);
    int[] array = new int[4];
    array[0] = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.LightSkyBlue);
    array[1] = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.Teal200);
    array[2] = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.LightGrey);
    array[3] = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.LightCoral);
    int randomColor = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
    CARD.setCardBackgroundColor(randomColor);
```

Layout file hierarchy like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardMechInfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    FAB:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        > ..........
```

The problem is when random color sets, the color seems to be appearing at the end of the card like a thinned line.

Did anybody faced problem like this. Please suggest how to solve this.

Thanks,
Pusp

Comment: what is a child of your card view? does it have a solid background?

Comment: Please see the edited code, yes solid background

Comment: The problem is random int array.length, the card.setBackGroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.someColor)); Works

Comment: array.length is 4, so what kind of problem could it be with number 4? just `Log.d` the value of `Integer.toHexString(randomColor)`

Comment: Log.d("Color", String.valueOf(randomcolor));  returns random array no like D/Color﹕ 1, D/Color﹕ 0 so forth.

Comment: Sorry, Log.d("Color", Integer.toHexString(randomcolor)); this returns the same thing like above 
D/Color﹕ 1

Comment: `int randomColor = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92023/discussion-between-pusp-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

It seems pskink pointed out me that the random value returns some surprise values, As he suggested me to use this :

```
int randomColor = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
```

Then it works on the cardView.

Answer (score 1):

The LinearLayout inside the card has width and height of match_parent, so it is obscuring most of the card's background.

Comment: But when i set the color via xml it works, weird though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've got a `LinearLayout` inside that `CardView` and have `5dp` margins around it.

If your `LinearLayout` has a non-transparent background, you will no longer see background of the `CardView`. So, you could set background of that `LinearLayout` to transparent or semi-transparent, then you can see `CardView`'s background.

**Fully transparent:**

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

For semi-transparent, you could set it's alpha channel.

Comment: Nope, i tried to set programatically it never works...I've tried what you said it just don't work.